# Not handling IA32 exception?

Tags: handler, interrupt, x86

What happens if i.e, in the IDT entry 0, I set the P (Present) bit to zero?

That translate to not handling a possible zero division.

Suppose the CPU does a zero division... what happens in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should get a #GP.  If the #GP handler is not present, you'll probably end up in Triple-Fault Shutdown.